# Azure DevOps - Should I merge code from origin to my branch and commit?

Tags: git, azure-devops

We have just moved to Azure DevOps and Git. We are relatively new in this area. From what we have read on **MSDN**:

We have an `origin/main-branch`, where no one is able to push their commits into. It consists of up to date codes that compiles.

Suppose I have a new feature, I create a local branch `myBranch` from the `origin/main-branch`.

I add my feature, then commit & push the branch `myBranch` to the repo. Then I initiate a pull request.

Upon that, it tells me that I have a conflict. I go in my VS and merge from origin/main-branch to my `myBranch`. I resolve the conflicts.

When I get to commit & push my changed files, I get other files that have been changed, when I didn't do any change.

My question is that should I commit & push these files also ?

Comment: "other files", would these be the files that you resolved during the merge conflict?

Comment: No not these files.

Comment: He might be referring to auto-generated files by the IDE that should be ignored in the `.gitignore`.

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer. Can you give us an example of what kind files you're talking about?

Comment: When you say "push the branch `myBranch` to the repo", what does that entail? Based on the description, the upstream should be `origin/main-branch` - which doesn't allow commits, so this should fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git keeps an entire history of all changes made in your repo. Generally, Git can order the changes and resolve the merge automatically according with the history as well as the relationships between commits, but if it's not clear from your history how changes to the same lines in the same files should merge, conflicts will occur. Please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio).

May i know how did you resolve the conflicts, and did you compare the changed file with them in your `main-branch` or `myBranch`?

> When I get to commit & push my changed files, I get other files that
>   have been changed, when I didn't do any change.

The change not only includes the text content, but also inlcudes encoding format. Sometimes, we use different editor to modify the file will cause the encoding format transfer. You can compare the files with binary.

I can not say that you should commit & push these files, it is recommended to check the changes and the impact of this change.